# DNS configuration not working

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system

Ok so I have a sub-domain which is running under cdn.sitename.com here is the thing, I do not wish nor do I desire to show the user the location of static files (ex: user uploaded files/system files)

So what I did is this added a CNAME record

Name: cdn-lln.sitename.com 
TTL: 14400
Class: IN
Type: CNAME
Record: cdn.sitename.com

But when I got to cdn-lln.sitename.com/folder path/ect/ect it gives me a 403 error and if I point it to a file which is located on cdn.sitename.com it returns me a 404 not found error

Can some one explain the problem and why this is happening?

- Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"cdn-lln.sitename.com/folder path/ect/ect it gives me a 403 error"

Have you updated your web server with the new CNAME?